# iterating through specified axis in cython

Tags: python, numpy, pointers, iterator, cython

I am learning cython and I have modified the code in the [tutorial](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/tutorials-numpy) to try to do numerical differentiation:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
import cython
np.import_array()

def test3(a, int order=2, int axis=-1):

    cdef int i

    if axis<0:
        axis = len(a.shape) + axis

    out = np.empty(a.shape, np.double)

    cdef np.flatiter ita = np.PyArray_IterAllButAxis(a, &axis)
    cdef np.flatiter ito = np.PyArray_IterAllButAxis(out, &axis)

    cdef int a_axis_stride = a.strides[axis]
    cdef int o_axis_stride = out.strides[axis]

    cdef int axis_length = out.shape[axis]

    cdef double value


    while np.PyArray_ITER_NOTDONE(ita):
        # first element
        pt1 = <double*>((<char*>np.PyArray_ITER_DATA(ita)))
        pt2 = (<double*>((<char*>np.PyArray_ITER_DATA(ita)) + 1*a_axis_stride))
        pt3 = (<double*>((<char*>np.PyArray_ITER_DATA(ita)) + 2*a_axis_stride))
        value = -1.5*pt1[0] + 2*pt2[0] - 0.5*pt3[0]
        (<double*>((<char*>np.PyArray_ITER_DATA(ito))))[0] = value

        for i in range(axis_length-2):
            pt1 = (<double*>((<char*>np.PyArray_ITER_DATA(ita)) + i*a_axis_stride))
            pt2 = (<double*>((<char*>np.PyArray_ITER_DATA(ita)) + (i+2)*a_axis_stride))
            value = -0.5*pt1[0] + 0.5*pt2[0]
            (<double*>((<char*>np.PyArray_ITER_DATA(ito)) + (i+1)*o_axis_stride))[0] = value

        # last element
        pt1 = (<double*>((<char*>np.PyArray_ITER_DATA(ita))+ (axis_length-3)*a_axis_stride))
        pt2 = (<double*>((<char*>np.PyArray_ITER_DATA(ita))+ (axis_length-2)*a_axis_stride))
        pt3 = (<double*>((<char*>np.PyArray_ITER_DATA(ita))+ (axis_length-1)*a_axis_stride))
        value = 1.5*pt3[0] - 2*pt2[0] + 0.5*pt1[0]
        (<double*>((<char*>np.PyArray_ITER_DATA(ito))+(axis_length-1)*o_axis_stride))[0] = value


        np.PyArray_ITER_NEXT(ita)
        np.PyArray_ITER_NEXT(ito)

    return out
```

The code produces correct results, and it is indeed faster than my own numpy implementation without cython. The problem is the following:

1. I thought about only having one `pt1 = (<double*>((<char*>np.PyArray_ITER_DATA(ita)) + i*a_axis_stride))` statement and then use `pt1[0]`, `pt1[-1]`, `pt1[1]` to access the array elements, but this only works if the specified axis is the last one. If I am differentiating a different axis (not the last one), then `(<double*>((<char*>np.PyArray_ITER_DATA(ita)) + i*a_axis_stride))` points to the right one, but `pt[-1]` and `pt[1]` point to the elements right before and after `pt[0]`, which is along the last axis. The current version works, but if I want to implement higher-order differentiation which requires more points to evaluate, then I will end up having many such lines, and I'm not sure if there are better/more efficient ways to do it using `pt[1]` or
   something like `pt[xxx]` to access neighbouring points (along the specified axis).
2. Are there other ways to speed up this piece of code? I am looking for some minor details that I may have overlooked or subtle things that can have a big effect.

Comment: Whatever speedup you're going to get almost certainly isn't worth just using regular slicing on a memoryview and turning off bounds checking and wraparound.

Comment: I'd guess the point of this would be to have something that works on an array with an arbitrary number of dimensions (which wouldn't be _that_ easy to do  with memoryviews). I don't immediately see why it wouldn't work (with the correct `cimport` from numpy included...), but I'm pretty sure a memoryview solution would be faster (if feasible)

Comment: Yeah I forgot to include `np.import_array()` in the question. Already edited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my slight surprise I can't actually beat your version using Cython typed memoryviews - the numpy iterators look pretty quick. However I think I can manage a significant increase in readability to let you use the Python slicing syntax. The only restriction is that the input array must be C contiguous to allow it to be reshaped easily (I think Fortran contiguous might also work, but I haven't tested)

The basic trick is to flatten all the axes before and after selected axis so it is a known 3D shape, at which point you can use Cython memoryviews.

```
@cython.boundscheck(False)
def test4(a,order=2,axis=-1):
    assert a.flags['C_CONTIGUOUS'] # otherwise the reshape doesn't work
    before = np.product(a.shape[:axis])
    after = np.product(a.shape[(axis+1):])
    cdef double[:,:,::1] a_new = a.reshape((before, a.shape[axis], after)) # this should not involve copying memory - it's just a new view
    cdef double[:] a_slice

    cdef double[:,:,::1] out = np.empty_like(a_new)

    assert a_new.shape[1] > 3

    cdef int m,n,i

    for m in range(a_new.shape[0]):
        for n in range(a_new.shape[2]):
            a_slice = a_new[m,:,n]

            out[m,0,n] = -1.5*a_slice[0] + 2*a_slice[1] - 0.5*a_slice[2]


            for i in range(a_slice.shape[0]-2):
                out[m,i+1,n] = -0.5*a_slice[i] + 0.5*a_slice[i+2]

            # last element
            out[m,-1,n] = 1.5*a_slice[-1] - 2*a_slice[-2] + 0.5*a_slice[-3]

    return np.asarray(out).reshape(a.shape)
```

The speed is very slightly slower than your version I think.

---

In terms of improving your code, you could work out the stride in doubles instead of bytes (`a_axis_stride_dbl = a_axis_stride/sizeof(double)`) and then index as `pt[i*a_axis_stride_dbl]`). It probably won't gain much speed but will be more readable. (This is what you ask about in point 1)

Comment: To me it looks like the bottle neck here is the memory bandwidth, it doesn’t play a huge role which syntax is used to access the memory, but it is all about the memory access pattern which would benefit most from the cache. One could see the differences by timing for big arrays and different axes: different timings are mostly due to different memory access pattern. I guess using some kind of tiling could be the key to performance here.